# Where's the conspiracy?

Tags: discussion

On the Mathematics Meta question promoting HSM (actually on my "answer"), there were [some comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/history-of-science-and-math-is-now-in-public-beta/17318?noredirect=1#comment64549_17318) made about the birth of this site. According to the accuser, it was conceived by "power-hungry users" instead of by "genuine public demand". The user also cast doubt on the ability of Danu to moderate - insinuating that he was part of the circle.

I responded via this in my answer (as well as through comments):

> Note: [Name of commenter] has be insinuating that the formation of the site was actually the result of a plan between "power-hungry users". This seems to be baseless. I checked the commitment and followers stats on Area 51, and a) Danu (whom [Name of commenter] seems to be alluding to) did not join the proposal/commitment for a long time, and b) Neither did any of the other high-rep users currently on HSM - at least, not as early as would be expected of a group guilty of conspiracy. I could, of course, be completely wrong about everything I'm saying, but it seems highly unlikely that this is the case.

Am I crazy, or what? Why does this user think there was this "narrow circle"?

I have absolutely no idea what to tag this question with, by the way. The whole situation is ridiculous.

Comment: There is no conspiracy HDE, and stop talking to that person. He sees no merit in our site and looks to be baiting you into some sort of argument. What started there as a harmless attempt to promote our site was not supposed to regress into that drivel. Look at his profile, he has been in all of SE for about 3 months registered. He is probably not aware that we do not vote for pro tem moderators, the stackexchange staff does that. There is no conspiracy. He just does not like our site. It might be best to not respond to him and let someone else sort him out, ... or not.

Comment: @J.W.Perry thats what someone in a consparicy would say

Answer (score 3):

There is no conspiracy here. But people on the internet believe all sorts of absurd things. Stack Exchange is not an exception to that. You'll notice that the comments the user made on your post have no upvotes. He's also a relatively new user with little experience on SE. I don't know why he thinks that this is a conspiracy, but I also don't care and you're wasting your time and energy if you do. The best course of action is to ignore comments like this. Definitely don't bother engaging them; that's a waste of everyone's time. If the user persists in making annoying and irrelevant comments, flag your post for moderator attention.

There's no need to engage every critic. We don't need to be defensive of this site. Don't bother trying to convince people on the internet who have no interest in being convinced of anything. If we do a good job, the content will speak for itself.

Comment: I think I've had some mildly unpleasant (really quite mild) encounters with this particular user on [physics.se] before; I guess that's where this is coming from.